# getting minutes difference between two Time::Piece objects

Tags: perl, datetime

I have the code:

```
use Time::Piece;
use Time::Seconds;

my $timespan = $latest_time - $timestamp;

print $latest_time . "\n";
print $timestamp . "\n";
print $timespan->minutes;
```

where $latest_time = Time::Piece->new; and $timestamp = Time::Piece->strptime();

and I get the results:

```
Thu Mar 27 09:40:19 2014
Thu Mar 27 09:40:00 2014
-479.683333333333
```

What went wrong? there should be 0 minutes for $timespan, correct? Where is -479 coming from?

Comment: 479.683 seconds is a wee bit shy of 8 hours. What time zone are you in?

Comment: GMT +8. so this doesn't assume that both objects are in the same timezone because of the Time::Piece->new; ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Reproducing the *"bug"***

This issue arises because strptime defaults to UTC instead of to the local timezone.  This can be demonstrated in the following code which takes a current time, prints it out, then reparses it and shows the difference:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::Piece;

my $now = Time::Piece->new();
print $now->strftime(), "\n";
my $fmt = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S";

my $nowstr = $now->strftime($fmt);
my $parsed = Time::Piece->strptime("$nowstr", $fmt);
print "($nowstr)\n";
print $parsed->strftime(), "\n";

my $diff = $now - $parsed;
print $diff->hours, " hours difference\n";
```

Outputs:

```
Wed, 26 Mar 2014 21:42:08 Pacific Daylight Time
(2014-03-26 21:42:08)
Wed, 26 Mar 2014 21:42:08 UTC
7 hours difference
```

**One hackish solution - getting parsed times to read as local**

Now, in hacking around, I've discovered one potential *hack* for this on my strawberry perl system.  It's by calling `strptime` like this: `$now->strptime`.

```
my $nowstr = "2014-03-26 21:51:00";   #$now->strftime($fmt);
my $parsed = $now->strptime("$nowstr", $fmt);   #Time::Piece->strptime("$nowstr", $fmt);
print "($nowstr)\n";
print $parsed->strftime(), "\n";

my $diff = $now - $parsed;
print $diff->hours, " hours difference\n";
```

To confirm that `strptime` was actually using the time I set it, I gave it one that was 6 minutes before the current time.  The output is as follows:

```
Wed, 26 Mar 2014 21:57:00 Pacific Daylight Time
(2014-03-26 21:51:00)
Wed, 26 Mar 2014 21:51:00 Pacific Standard Time
0.1 hours difference
```

The parsed time will inherit the `c_islocal` value from `$now`.  `$now` just needs to be initialized with either `localtime` or `->new()` and not `gmtime` of course.

As you can see one claims DST while the other does not, but date math is still done correctly.  I was able to figure out this hack by looking at the source for `strptime`, `_mktime`, and `new`.

Hopefully, at the very least my code to reproduce the error will be helpful to someone with more experience with `Time::Piece`, and I'd love a better solution.

Comment: adding the 8000 timezone (GMT +8) hint in the strptime corrects the time difference result but the date time displayed is now ahead by 8 hours when i use strftime. why is that? anyways the timezone problem is solved now. i'm just curious about the strftime thing

Comment: (Perl 5.10.1) `Time::Piece->strptime` gave me local time instead of **UTC**

Answer (score 0):

When I use `strftime("%H:%M:%S %Z")` for both `$latest_time` and `$timestamp` they both show the same timezone, but the `$latest_time - $timestamp` operation shows that there is difference between the timezones as tobyink pointed out. This might be a bug in Time::Piece module.

So it seems that `Time::Piece->new;` gets the current machine time including the timezone.

So either I fix the timezone in `Time::Piece->new` or include a timezone value when I use `Time::Piece->strptime();` to fix the timezone problem. Thanks for the info, tobyink.