# Time::Piece (localtime/gmtime) calculation vs bash date

Tags: perl

Have this `bash` script:

```
future="${1:-Dec 08 2017 22:00:00}"
t1=$(date -j -f "%b %d %Y %H:%M:%S" "$future" +%s)  #using OS X
t0=$(date +%s)

echo "Current: $(date)"
echo "Future : $future"
echo "Diff   : $(( $t1 - $t0 )) secs"
```

It prints:

```
Current: pi   8. december 2017 21:25:25 CET
Future : Dec 08 2017 22:00:00
Diff   : 2075 secs
```

The result (diff) is correct.

Now trying to do the same using perl:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Time::Piece;

my $format = '%b %d %Y %H:%M:%S';

my $future = shift // 'Dec 08 2017 22:00:00';
say "Future: $future";

say "localtime: ", scalar localtime();
say "gmtime   : ", scalar gmtime();

my $tf = Time::Piece->strptime($future, $format);
say 'localtime-diff : ', $tf-localtime();
say 'gmtime-diff    : ', $tf-gmtime();
```

it prints

```
Future: Dec 08 2017 22:00:00
localtime: Fri Dec  8 21:27:45 2017  #correct
gmtime   : Fri Dec  8 20:27:45 2017  #correct
localtime-diff : 5535 #incorrect (expecting 3600 secs less)
gmtime-diff    : 5535 #ok
```

What is wrong? Mean, why it prints the same diff for the `localtime` and `gmtime` but the `scalar localtime` and `scalar gmtime` prints different (and correct) strings?

EDIT: So, the main question is: how to get the same result as in bash using perl?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both `localtime()` and `gmtime()` return an object that represents *now*.

---

You are doing:

```
2017-12-08T22:00:00+00:00 - 2017-12-08T21:25:25+01:00   # $tf-localtime()
2017-12-08T22:00:00+00:00 - 2017-12-08T20:25:25+00:00   # $tf-gmtime()
```

It looks like you want to do

```
2017-12-08T22:00:00+01:00 - 2017-12-08T21:25:25+01:00
```

---

Using Time::Piece:

```
use Time::Piece qw( localtime );

my $future_str = 'Dec 08 2017 23:00:00';

my $format = '%b %d %Y %H:%M:%S';

my $future_dt = localtime->strptime($future_str, $format);
say $future_dt - localtime();  # 2241 (instead of 5841)
```

---

Using DateTime:

```
use DateTime::Format::Strptime qw( );

my $future_str = 'Dec 08 2017 23:00:00';

my $format = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
   pattern   => '%b %d %Y %H:%M:%S',
   locale    => 'en',
   time_zone => 'local',
   on_error  => 'croak',
);

my $future_dt = $format->parse_datetime($future_str);
say $future_dt->epoch - time();  # 2241 (instead of 5841)
```

Comment: Ahhhh.. So, blindly copy the docs, and calling the `strptime` as an class method is the source of the problem. :( I wasn't realised, that I should (and could) call it as obj.method on the `localtime` and `gmtime` - and thinking about _what is the `now`_ (as you commented). It is so simple, when someone clearly explains it.. :) :) Thank you very much!

Comment: Time::Piece->strptime (or gmtime->Time::Piece) causes the resulting object is marked as UTC dt. localtime->strptime marks it as a local dt. The ability to do `localtime->strptime` is rather new, and this behaviour is undocumented, but it's the only way without messing with internals.

Comment: The hack is been around for a while:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/22678705/1733163   Wish they'd just document this.

Comment: @Miller, Most people use 5.14 and the Time::Piece that comes with it, which is older than that post.

Comment: @ikegami *nod*.  That post was using Perl 5.10.1.  I never bothered doing a comprehensive inventory of version support though.